# SQL return rows based on column value condition

Tags: sql, boolean-logic, sql-function

I have below tables

Order Table

```
OrderNo  CategoryID  SubCategoryID  CountryID
 100         7         1             3
 200         8         2             5
 300         7         2             4
 400         2         6             2
```

Tracking Table

```
OrderNo  CountryID   TrackingTypeID
 100        2             1
 200        1             2
 100        3             3
 400        5             5
 200        2             2
```

Reviewed Table

```
 OrderNo 
   300
   100
   200
```

Expected Result

```
OrderNo  SubCategoryID  CategoryID  CountryID   CountryID   
  100       1             7            3           3
  200       2             8            5           5
  300       2             7            4           4
```

Each subCategory belongs to one Category.

Now I want to write a query for below requirements.

1. Returns only orders of `CategoryID` (7,8)

   1.1 In case the order has `SubCategoryID` (1,4)
   return only orders which has a record in Tracking table with
   same `CountryID` as in `Order` table.
   And that order should not have a `TrackingTypeID` of (5,6) in Tracking
   table.

   1.2 In case the order has `SubCategoryID` (2,6) then that order must
   have a record in `Reviewed` table and that order should not have a
   `TrackingTypeID` (5,6) in `Tracking` table
2. Exclude all orders which have `SubCategoryID` that not belong to `CategoryID` (7,8)

I wrote below script but the issue is that it's always run the second condition only.And no order which satisfies the first condition is being returned.
But if I run the script with the first condition only I get these orders. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.orderNo , o.subCategoryId , o.categoryId ,
            o.countryId , Tracking.countryId

FROM [Order] o

JOIN Tracking ON o.orderNo = Tracking.orderNo 

WHERE
 (o.subCategoryId IN (1,4 ) AND o.countryId = Tracking.countryId  AND
   EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM tracking t
           WHERE t.orderNo = o.orderNo AND t.countryId = o.countryId)
           AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM tracking t
                 WHERE t.orderNo = o.orderNo 
                 AND TrackingTypeID IN (5,6))
          
        )
        
  OR
   
  (o.subCategoryId  in (
      SELECT id FROM subCatgory WHERE categoryId in (7,8)
      AND  ID NOT IN (1 , 4)
      ) 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM Reviewed r
           WHERE r.orderNo = r.orderNo
          )

      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM tracking t
                 WHERE t.orderNo = o.orderNo 
                 AND TrackingTypeID IN (5,6))
  )
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ presented as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: I will update it. I though it would be much readable as images

Comment: Start with specifying the expected result - so we don't have to guess if we have understood the problem.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenient. I updated the question

Comment: No problem! We are all here to learn.